# Restore from Azure blob storage failing after backup overwrite

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, azure

I'm attempting to backup a database (full backup, in simple recovery) to Azure storage, replacing a bak file that already exists, then restoring the new backup. Doing a regular backup and restore works fine, but when I replace a backup in Azure using `WITH FORMAT`, any subsequent restore commands fail with `The media family on device 'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/dbname.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.`

Here's the backup SQL:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [dbname]
TO URL = 'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/dbname.bak'
WITH FORMAT;
```

This is with a backup already existing at that URI. This part succeeds, and I can see that the modify date of the blob has been updated. Then running:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY
FROM URL = 'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/dbname.bak'
```

fails with the above mentioned error. I get the error whether I'm on a different instance or on the same instance as the original database. Is using `WITH FORMAT` actually corrupting the backup? What am I doing wrong here?

This seems to be the [recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-2017) to overwrite Azure blob backups.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 SP2. I tried `CHECKSUM` and didn't get any error. I'll attempt again using `INIT`.